# Express routing templates

Tags: javascript, html, templates

I am using ExpressJS with EJS templating. I have never used any form of templates. I am trying to reuse views or templates ( not quite sure the difference ). I feel like there are multiple ways for specific elements in a view to be conditionally exposed based on how/where that view was rendered. Is there a standard protocol for passing the conditional parameter to the view?

I was assuming it was passed in something like this:

```
     res.render('/niceview', function(req, res) {
             parameter: "myIndicatingParameter"
        });
```

I think this could work but I would like to follow standards and could not seem to find an indication of the proper method for this action. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.render()` can take an object as second argument to pass variables to the template:

```
res.render('niceview', {
  myIndicatingParameter : true
});
```

Comment: Oh ok. I was actually just try to figure out why I would use locals instead of that method.

Comment: `res.locals` is usually used from middleware, where variables are set that *eventually* end up in a template (like a User object that's been read from the database: the middleware loads it, adds it to `res.locals`, and it will be available to any templates used after that middleware).

Comment: oh nice Thanks, I will definitely be able to use that for another part of my code.

Answer (score 1):

Use [res.locals](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals) to send variables to the view rendering engine.

```
res.locals({myIndicatingParameter: true});
res.render('/niceview');
```